# How to vertically center text within a box in Inkscape, obtaining the same result than CSS "align-items: center;"?

Tags: inkscape, text, alignment

I have been trying to vertically center text within a box in Inkscape 1.2, using the tool circled in red:

[image]

The result isn't perfect: as you can see, the text is aligned using the height of the highest character (the "A" on the left, and the "x" on the right).

The result I would like is this:

[image]

This is done using HTML/CSS. The boxes have the following CSS properties that result in the wanted vertical alignment:

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

How can I achieve this kind of vertical alignment in Inkscape?

On a side note, I noticed that the height of the selection box is used to center the text in the last example:

[image]

I'm not shure how the height of this selection box is calculated though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way, but you can drag a text boundary with the text tool that is the same size as the rectangle object using snapping, then set the line-height to the height of the box in 'px' (or 'mm' etc.) in the toolbar.

[image: Line-height setting highlighted in the toolbar]

This is equivalent to the old CSS trick of using `line-height` to center text:

```css
.box {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```